# Grepping list of phpass hashes against a file

Tags: grep, cygwin, phpass

I'm trying to grep multiple strings which look like this (there's a few hundred) against a file which contains `data:string`

Example strings: (no sensitive data is provided, they have been modified).

```
$H$9a...DcuCqC/rMVmfiFNm2rqhK5vFW1  
$H$9n...AHZAV.sTefg8ap8qI8U4A5fY91  
$H$9o...Bi6Z3E04x6ev1ZCz0hItSh2JJ/  
$H$9w...CFva1ddp8IRBkgwww3COVLf/K1
```

I've been researching how to grep a file of patterns against another file, and came across the following commands

```
grep -f strings.txt datastring.txt > output.txt  
grep -Ff strings.txt datastring.txt > output.txt
```

But unfortunately, these commands do NOT work successfully, and only print out a handful of results to my output file. I think it may be something to do with the symbols contained in strings.txt, but I'm unsure. Any help/advice would be great.

To further mention, I'm using Cygwin on Windows (if this is relevant).

Here's an updated example:
strings.txt contains the following:

```
$H$9a...DcuCqC/rMVmfiFNm2rqhK5vFW1  
$H$9n...AHZAV.sTefg8ap8qI8U4A5fY91  
$H$9o...Bi6Z3E04x6ev1ZCz0hItSh2JJ/  
$H$9w...CFva1ddp8IRBkgwww3COVLf/K1
```

datastring.txt contains the following:

```
$H$9a...DcuCqC/rMVmfiFNm2rqhK5vFW1:53491  
$H$9n...AHZAV.sTefg8ap8qI8U4A5fY91:03221  
$H$9o...Bi6Z3E04x6ev1ZCz0hItSh2JJ/:20521  
$H$9w...CFva1ddp8IRBkgwww3COVLf/K1:30142
```

So technically, all lines should be included in the OUTPUT file, but only this line is outputted:

```
$H$9w...CFva1ddp8IRBkgwww3COVLf/K1:30142
```

I just don't understand.

Comment: It's not clear why `-Ff` isn't working.  There must be a difference in the lines that you expect that don't appear in the output.

Comment: Hi, I'm going to update my post and show an example, maybe this can help the understanding because I explained it poorly.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have showed the output of `cat -A strings.txt` elsewhere, which includes `^M` representing a CR (carriage return) character at the end of each line:

[image: screenshot]

This indicates your file has Windows line endings (CR LF) instead of the Unix line endings (only LF) that `grep` would expect.

You can convert files with `dos2unix strings.txt` and back with `unix2dos strings.txt`.

Alternatively, if you don't have dos2unix installed in your Cygwin environment, you can also do that with `sed`.

```sh
sed -i 's/\r$//' strings.txt    # dos2unix
sed -i 's/$/\r/' strings.txt    # unix2dos
```